# Not a bit of free time!

Tags: vocabulary

My intention is to say that "I have no free time in the present project".

But I always say "I am totally packed in the present project".  Not sure packed is correct word.

Could you guys please tell me what all the other ways I could say I am full busy, in the above scenario.

Comment: In American English, *you* would not usually be packed, but your *schedule* (or *life* or *week*, etc.) could be, e.g. *Sorry, my calendar is completely packed*. To say *I am packed* would usually be interpreted as metonymy for *my bags are packed*, whether literally (as before a trip) or figuratively (to indicate that you are prepared to leave something).

Answer (score 1):

You could use idioms for this. I'll give you a few suggestions you could use to give the listener an impression that you are extremely busy and cannot spare a second.

> - "I'm *slammed* with work now."
> - "I'm upto my ears with tasks to complete."
> - “I’m feeling a little overwhelmed at present."
> - "I'm sweating blood to finish this project on time."

Also, you could use an element of humor to convey that you are busy, thereby keeping things pleasant with a mild comedy, say for example,

> - "I'm running around like Santa on Christmas eve."

You could really mix things up and use metaphors that depicts an action or activity that involves being very busy also.

Comment: @JavaLatte, edits made.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say that you are busy working on the project, you can say '*I am too engrossed in the current project*'.

If you mean to say that you are busy on some other work and do not have time to work on the project, you can say '*I am too busy for this project*'.

There are other words you can use to describe how busy you are, like 'occupied', 'engaged', etc.

Comment: "engrossed" is used only about things that capture your interest completely. You would only use it about a project if it was something very unusual or interesting. The normal preposition with "engrossed" is "in"... "engrossed in".

Comment: Hmm.. 'Engrossed for' does seem weird. Thanks for pointing out. Changing the second sentence in my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [flat-out](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flat--out):

> I am working flat-out on the current project

or

> I am very busy on the current project

Answer (score 0):

The phrases you are using to describe being busy do not sound correct to me. Let me suggest some alternatives.

`I have no free time in the present project` -> `I have no free time to work on this project`

`I am totally packed in the present project` -> `I am totally slammed by this project right now`

`I am full busy` -> `I am very busy` or `I am completely busy`

I am not familiar with the term `flat out`. Personally I would say `all out`.